# Writing multiple string elements to a list

Tags: python-3.x, intellisense, visual-studio-code

How can I write this more efficiently. For example when I'm declaring a list with multiple string elements, it gets bothersome to have to press <kbd>-></kbd> to move past the second quotation mark to add a comma.

Usually after writing functions or for loops I just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> or <kbd>END</kbd> to get to the end to append a colon. But with lists and strings, it's quite bothersome, would appreciate some help

```
my_list = ["word|"] 
if I press END 
my_list = ["word"]|
```

and then I have to do <kbd><-</kbd> to go back and write more strings.

Hopefully I've been

```
blinking | marker = | 
my_list = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7"]
```

Comment: Perhaps, you could place the closing `]` on the next line.  That way, when you press END, it will take to the last string and you could continue adding comma + next string.  Another tidbit to consider:  add a comma after the last string.  It makes list more manageable if you need to add or remove items from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way for quick small lists:

```
    my_list = 'word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7'.split()  
    print(my_list)

    ## ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7']
```